# On-off controller open loop or close loop?

Tags: control, system

Are all On-off controllers used for close loop control systems or can also be used for open loop control systems?

Comment: Yes .. Bangbang!

Comment: The word "controller" implies feedback (else it would be called a driver i.e. on/off driver). An on/off driver has no feedback but, when feedback is implemented it becomes an on/off controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be used for either.

- A thermostat, such as a bimetallic strip type, is an on-off controller which is used in a closed loop to control room temperature. As the temperature rises above setpoint the heat is turned off. As the temperature falls below setpoint the heat is turned on.
- The same heating system could be run from a timer that applies heat for 6 minutes on and 4 minutes off in a repeating pattern. This is open loop. There is no temperature feedback to modify the action of the timer.